# Cannot use windows_package in chef. Installer_type broken

Tags: windows, chef-infra

No matter what I pass in it yells at me for the argument being invalid in some shape or form.

```
Unable to find a Chef::Provider::Package::Windows provider for installer_type ':msi'
Option installer_type must be a kind of [String]!  You passed :msi.
Unable to find a Chef::Provider::Package::Windows provider for installer_type 'msi'
```

Maybe I am doing something wrong with the rest of the declaration. Here is what it is translated to by chef:

```
 windows_package("Some Software") do
  provider Chef::Provider::Package::Windows
  action [:remove]
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  guard_interpreter :default
  package_name "Some Software"
  source "C:\\Some Software"
  installer_type "msi"
  timeout 600
  returns [0]
  cookbook_name "Some-Cookbook"
  recipe_name "default"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The `windows_package` provider was only recently added to Chef core. If you are using an older version of the Chef Client, you will need to add a dependency on the [windows cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/windows).

Comment: I am using the latest version I believe

Comment: Have you tried using the windows cookbook? It's also possible you've found a bug too :)

Comment: I must be doing something stupid now but I am still having issues:

`include_recipe windows::default

package "Somepackage" do
    action :remove
end`

This throws 'You must supply a name when declaring a windows resource'

Comment: use `windows_package`, not `package`

Comment: I have done both, same result. And I do have the windows package installed :P